# Network problems Ethernet + Wifi after clean install Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet, internet-connection, network-adapter

I'm having trouble accessing the network on either Ethernet or Wifi. 
There are several other devices connected to the network and none of them have trouble accessing the network, and even when all of them are disconnected, that doesn't change anything for my internet speed on that PC. My PC IS loading the pages, once I even had a decent connection and videos and pages loaded, but most of the time, it would just take an eternity to load and then eventually fail after 2 or 3 websites.

I recently wiped my SSD and HDD and did a clean install of Windows 10, I made sure I updated and installed the drivers but nothing. Before that clean install, I had no issues.

I have a PCi Wifi Adapter, Qualcomm Atheros AR938x, bought a new Ethernet-Cable, but I don't think the problem lies there as there's no difference when I switch.
I can reach google.com instantly, can google for websites, but when it comes to accessing a webiste google returns me a link for, my connection fails.

Here are my system specs if that is any help:

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz 4.01 GHz
RAM 16 GB
Motherboard is the Z-170a Pro 
and well my graphics card is the GTX 1070.

Comment: Your problem description is confusing.  You say you can reach Google.com but cannot access it.  What revision of the driver are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for that, I meant that if I try to access the webiste I was googling for, the page loads and loads and then fails. What driver do you mean?

Comment: Your adapter device driver.  Although using a lan cable with a 802.11 adapter doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I fixed it by resetting windows. I'll see if the problem returns if I update the drivers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is a problem with the wipe and reinstall of Windows.

Make sure that:

1) **your PCi works correctly.** There isn't generally a way to find out whether it works correctly or not...  Just by plugging another device that works thru PCi.

If there is a problem with the port, the only way to fix it, is by changing your motherboard. And that's not an easy step if you are not familiar with PC hardware.. *(If you want to change Motherboard, just reply to me and I'll find the best for you by your specs and budget...)*

2) **your Ethernet Card works correctly.** The only way to prove it, is to change it. *As you also mention, no other device works as slow as your PC. (And because of the slow Wi-Fi, the websites give you an error.)*

If wifi card is the point, you have a lot of solutions. ***a)*** Change the connection of the wifi card. So, if now it's PCi, and say that that PCi is broken, you can buy another wifi card for USB. Or PCi-E. That would not cost so much.  ***b)*** Buy a new motherboard, so that don't have to change your wifi card. ***c)*** Connect the Ethernet cable directly to your motherboard. *There is no way that your motherboard will not have internet port..*

***Hope I helped you! If you need anything, feel free to contact me!***

Comment: I chose to reset Windows but kept all my personal files. Apparently, that did it for me. I don't know whether it's about something I installed, but I'll pay attention to what I install or update (maybe the problem was a driver?) and how it affects my internet connection. 
Also, I used Cmd prompt and used ipconfig. I figured that before I chose to reset windows, all media was disconnected. But now I finally get the standardgateway Wifi-Adapter thingy.